# how "".value evaluates value in java String class?

Tags: java, string

Below is the code snippet taken from String.class.
how "".value evaluates value in java String class??

```
 private final char value[];
 /**
 * Initializes a newly created {@code String} object so that it represents
 * an empty character sequence.  Note that use of this constructor is
 * unnecessary since Strings are immutable.
 */
public String() {
    this.value = "".value;
}
```

I want to understand the default behavior of equals() in String..

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = value.length;
        if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                    return false;
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

}

so not clear how n is taking value from value.length from the above code..

Comment: this will help https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear (at least for me). What exactly is confusing you?

Comment: @CrazySabbath How is that related to autoboxing? `value` is `char[]` array and arrays are not boxed.

Comment: I want to understand the default behaviour of equals() in String..

Comment: Which part of `n = value.length` makes it "not clear how `n` is taking value from `value.length`"?

Answer (score 0):

`""` is a `String` like any other.

It was created by invoking a different constructor than the one shown here. That constructor has assigned an array to the `value` field; that value happens to be the same as `new char[0]`.

The constructor in the question is merely accessing the field of that string. It's like:

```
String empty = "";
this.value = empty.value;
```